# Im getting npm install error while creating ionic app in windows 10 , i've installed all necessary and environment variables are set

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, node-modules

[check error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjzur.jpg)

npm -v 5.3.0
node -v 8.4.0
cordova -v 7.0.1
ionic -v 3.9.2

this  is my environment variables path

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin;C:\Android_SDK_latest\platform-tC:\Android_SDK_latest\tools;C:\Android_SDK_latest\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\Maxwell laptop\AppData\Roaming\npm;ools;C:\Android_SDK_latest\tools;C:\Android_SDK_latest;

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall NodeJS and install NodeJS again. Preferable to install LTS Version from following link : 
https://nodejs.org/en/